# string.Format not working in C# razor when inside if statement

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I am using `string.Format` in a razor view to format items coming from my viewModel.

It is working fine when I use it like this:

```
<td>
   <b>@string.Format("{0:c}", item.TotalCreditPaid)</b>
</td>
```

But, when I try to use it within an if statement it is not displaying anything in the view:

```
      <td>
          <b>@if (item.AverageTimeToPay != null)
          {
            string.Format("{0} Days", item.AverageTimeToPay);
          }
          </b>
     </td>
```

I stepped through it and the if is being hit, the `item.AverageTimeToPay` has a value of 12, but it is not displaying anything.

Any idea why this is happening? Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are missing the `@` and parenthesis, change it to this instead.

```
  <td>
      @if (item.AverageTimeToPay != null)
      {
        <b>@(string.Format("{0} Days", item.AverageTimeToPay))</b>
      }
 </td>
```

Comment: No point in having an empty `<b>` rendered, I personally would move the `b` element inside of the if statement and use that to dictate the rendering of the value

Comment: I'll do that. This got it working though. I was putting the `@` symbol in front of the string without the parenthesis.

Comment: @musefan Correct, I agree but that is not what the question was. :)

Comment: @cfly24 No problem. Thanks. :)

Comment: @hutchonoid: yeah it's a fair point, though I think it's our duty to improve the code when answering if possible, but it's not a biggy. Also it isn't my downvote incase you was wondering

Comment: @musefan No I totally agree, it's best to provide the best answer possible. I'll add that to my answer. No worries for downvote, it happens sometimes.

Comment: Helps a lot! Thanks!

Comment: No problem @jackylalala 

Answer (score 2):

You are not rendering your output to Html as string,  You can do it in two ways

**1)**

```
 <b>
  @if (item.AverageTimeToPay != null)
  {
    @:@string.Format("{0} Days", item.AverageTimeToPay);
  }
  </b>
```

**2)**

```
  @if (item.AverageTimeToPay != null)
  {
    <b>@string.Format("{0} Days", item.AverageTimeToPay)</b>
  }
```

Check this 
 [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/8gwVdb)

Comment: I like the solution with `@:@`. Thanks! You should leave out the semicolon there, though. It will get rendered to the screen.

Answer (score 1):

The code is running, but it's not emitting anything to the page.

This will automatically emit to the page:

```
@string.Format("{0:c}", item.TotalCreditPaid)
```

because of how Razor syntax works.  Basically the output of the line of code is emitted to the page.  However, this is just plain code:

```
string.Format("{0} Days", item.AverageTimeToPay);
```

By itself it doesn't do anything, something needs to be done with its output.  In your second example, the output *of the `if` block* is emitted to the page, but `if` blocks don't output anything.  (The clue here is that semi-colon.  It's subtle, but it's kind of an indicator that this is just a server-side line of code and not a Razor output statement.)

All you need to do is tell it to output to the page:

```
<td>
    @if (item.AverageTimeToPay != null)
    {
        <b>@string.Format("{0} Days", item.AverageTimeToPay)</b>
    }
</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you aren't breaking out of the code block.

Try this instead:

```
  <td>
      @if (item.AverageTimeToPay != null)
      {
        <b>@string.Format("{0} Days", item.AverageTimeToPay)</b>
      }
 </td>
```

or

```
  <td>
      <b>@if (item.AverageTimeToPay != null)
      {
        @:@string.Format("{0} Days", item.AverageTimeToPay);
      }
      </b>
 </td>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to print the string to the page so try:

```
<td>
    <b>@if (item.AverageTimeToPay != null)
    {
        @string.Format("{0} Days", item.AverageTimeToPay);
    }
    </b>
</td>
```